# lazy evaluation of encrypted text stored in large NSArray

Tags: iphone, encryption, lazy-evaluation

I have to store about 10k text lines in an Array. Each line is stored as a separate encrypted entry. When the app runs I only need to access a small number and decrypt them - depending on user input. I thought of some kind of lazy evaluation but don't know how to do it in this case.

This is how I build up my array: `[allElements addObject:  @"wdhkasuqqbuqwz" ]` The string is encrypted. Accessing is like txt = `[[allElements objectAtIndex:n] decrypt]`

The problem currently is that this uses lots of memory from the very start - most of the items I don't need anyway, just don't know which ones ;). Also I am hesitant to store the text externally eg in a textfile, since this would make it easier to access it.

Is there a way to minimize memory usage in such a case?

ps initialization is very fast, so no issue here

Comment: What is the overall size of the array? (10K lines * howManyLines)?  Even a few MB should not be not a real problem.  Are you getting memory warnings?  What part could be lazy?

Comment: There are about 10k number of lines, each line is about 40 characters long. For some reason I get memory warnings sometimes level 1, seldom level2 on a 32 GB iPhone. I can't profile the app on the iPhone, there is a bug in Xcode (confirmed with Apple). So I like to reduce the risk of low memory. I was hoping to do some kind of lazy initialization of the array depending on the requested indices into the array.

Comment: Can you hold the data remotely in a database and just download the few lines needed?

Comment: Unfortunately the data has to be stored on the iPhone directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's quite a big array, although not really big enough to be triggering any huge memory warnings (unless my maths has gone horribly wrong, I reckon your array of 10,000 40-character strings is about 0.76 MB. Perhaps there are other things going on in your app causing these warnings - are you loading any large images or many assets?

What I'm a little confused about it how you're currently storing these elements before you initalise the array. Because you say you don't want to store the text externally in a text file, but you must be holding them in some kind of file before initialising your array, unless of course your values are generated on the fly.

If you've encrypted correctly, you shouldn't need to *care* whether your values are stored in plain-sight or not. Hopefully you're using an established standard and not rolling your own encryption, so really I think worrying about users getting hold of the file is a moot point. After all, the whole point of encryption is being able to hide data in plain sight.

I would recommend, as a couple of your commenters already have, is that you should just use some form of database storage. Core Data was made for this purpose - handling large amounts of data with minimal memory impact. But again, I'm not sure how that array alone could trigger a memory warning, so I suspect there's other stuff going on in your app that's eating up your memory.

Comment: Thanks, you made some very good points. I will try to profile my app (even though an Xcode bug currently doesn't allow it to be profiled on the iPhone). Hopefully profiling in the simulator will work sometime! The values are being generated in init routines as mentioned in my initial question - just a long source code file. Also Core Data might really be a good suggestion. So far I have not used it because I was not sure about the performance compared to simple arrays (which is absolutely OK) - Again thanks for these good suggestions - it will take me a while to check them out...

Comment: The nice thing about Core Data is it will by default lazily load items in as you need them, so hopefully it will be of some use!

Comment: Yes you are right - I have been using core data many times before - but for performance reason did not consider it this time so far. I will have to check how long it takes to initialize an array of such a size in core data. Also just a comment regarding encryption. I have read so many negative things about the built in encryption (easy to hack, problems with UTF-8, etc...) that I rather use my own (which has to be available under Windows in Excel for my purpose too)

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with writing an implementation of a common algorithm, but writing your own algorithms is a recipe for disaster - see the highest rated answer here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology